# How to suppress ITK warning messages in python

Tags: python, itk

Whenever I load .img.gz file using python medpy.io load function, I get a warning message like:

WARNING: In /usr/share/miniconda/envs/bld/conda-bld/simpleitk_1598369168428/work/build/ITK/Modules/IO/NIFTI/src/itkNiftiImageIO.cxx, line 1009
NiftiImageIO (0x56268f287910): /data/temp.img.gz is Analyze file and it's deprecated

Is there any way to suppress warning messages?
I tried to using import logging library and set logging.disable(sys.maxsize)
& import warnings and set
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=PendingDeprecationWarning)

Neither method worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

ITK warning message display can be globally toggled with `itk.ProcessObject.SetGlobalWarningDisplay`. So you want

```py
itk.ProcessObject.SetGlobalWarningDisplay(False)
```

See the static function `itk::Object::SetGlobalWarningDisplay`. [C++ docs here](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Object.html#a6a45f7507401b719a7de0c29375f5c5d).

Comment: This worked for me, and I think most specifically answers the OP's question about ITK.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [How to disable warning in simpleitk.ReadImage in Python](https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/issues/491) on Github.

> You can disable all warning displays of SimpleITK by calling [SetGlobalWarningDisplay](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1ProcessObject.html#a99d3df8ad7db82bc587edaa8706d135a).

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
from medpy.io import load

sitk.ProcessObject_SetGlobalWarningDisplay(False)
image_data, image_header = load('path/to/image.nii.gz')
sitk.ProcessObject_SetGlobalWarningDisplay(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't specify the category?

I do it this way in a case-by-case basis so that it doesn't affect the entire python file.

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    # do whatever after this
```

Update: It's probably an issue from the C++ side doing the warning rather than python. You'll have to dig into the C++ more to catch it.
https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/34231b57021418fdb6afd4fcf5082a73b12969ed/Modules/IO/NIFTI/src/itkNiftiImageIO.cxx#L1009 and then look at `itkWarningMacro`: https://itk.org/Doxygen318/html/itkMacro_8h.html#a0c47033c6ca9aae1319b1793f4419ada

Comment: I tried to access the itkNiftiImageIO.cxx, but I was not able to find it. It says miniconda folder does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, what I said was imprecise. If you change the C++ source then you'd need to recompile the python module. But you probably shouldn't do that. What I meant to say earlier is that you'd need to understand how C++ is logging it, what `itkWarningMacro` does, so that you have a chance of capturing it with Python. You may also check the NIFTI github page to create an issue or search for solutions.